# Parse ByteBuffer looking for whitespace

Tags: java, parsing, buffer, bytebuffer

I have a ByteBuffer containing some data (chars to be exact). How can I parse it to get only starting bytes up to first whitespace character ?

Comment: Are you talking about 1 byte or 2 byte chars?

Comment: What is the character encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way it to step threw the ByteBuffer until you get a whitespace. e.g.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char ch;
while(buffer.remaining() > 0 && !Character.isWhitespace(ch = (char) buffer.get()))
    sb.append(ch);
```

There are more efficient ways but that is perhaps the simplest.

Comment: Will the size of the chars matter for this?  Would `getchar()` be a better method to use?

Comment: @Jacob: Yes, size matters :-). `get()` is correct if each byte in the buffer represents an ASCII character (strict ASCII, i.e. value<128). `getChar()` is for data encoded as UCS-2 (I believe).

Comment: get() can also work if you assume no high bits if you get() & 0xFF

Answer (score 2):

Use the `getChar()` method and it will pull out the next char for you.  Check it and once you see a whitespace character.  Stop reading it.

Comment: -1 Without knowing the encoding, there is no way to know what `getChar()` will give you.

Comment: +1 Encoding is irrelevant here - you know exactly what getChar() will return. getChar() will give you two bytes according the current byte order; whether or not those two bytes match "whitespace" is up to you.  jzd's comment looks just fine to me.  (Granted, it moves quite a bit of the problem into the unstated whitespace check, but it's still correct.)